# Unable to hide cmd.exe when running the already converted file to .exe

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.7

I have searched and searched the web, try almost every code, but still unable to hide the cmd.exe from background(only happens when the command is to open an exe from computer - for example, open the word.exe), the other buttons don't open the cmd.exe, because is to open links from the web. I apologize, i'm a beginner in python, i just had the teacher give us the basics, but i went in love with python, so i decide to study at home and trying to do my on apps.
Many thanks for any given reply. Peace

Note: I have two files. one python that is already converted to exe, one in python itslef, i try pyw, pyc, opening in one python window and in the other one, everything you may think off i have done it. Now i'm working on the original file of python (boss.pyw) i will display the full code below and where should i put the command so the cmd.exe won't appear.

import functools
import sys
import ctypes
import urllib.request
import os
import webbrowser
from tkinter import *
import idlelib
from tkinter import messagebox
import tkinter as tk
import subprocess

```
def programs():

    class LoginFrame(Frame):
        def __init__(self, master):
            super().__init__(master)

            self.logbtn0 = Button(self, text="SKIDROW", command=self._login_btn_clicked0, fg='#ff00bf', height = 4, width = 12)
            self.logbtn0.grid(columnspan=4)
            self.logbtn6 = Button(self, text="""Planet
Romeo""", command=self._login_btn_clicked6, fg='#990000', height = 4, width = 12)
            self.logbtn6.grid(columnspan=4)
            self.logbtn7 = Button(self, text="""Sair
Programa""", command=self._login_btn_clicked7, fg='#b366ff', height = 4, width = 12)
            self.logbtn7.grid(columnspan=4)
            self.logbtn = Button(self, text="EXCEL", command=self._login_btn_clicked, fg='#00b33c', height = 4, width = 12)
            self.logbtn.grid(columnspan=2)
            self.logbtn1 = Button(self, text="WORD", command=self._login_btn_clicked1, fg='#ff4000', height = 4, width = 12)
            self.logbtn1.grid(columnspan=2)
            self.logbtn5 = Button(self, text="FILMORA", command=self._login_btn_clicked5, fg='#ff00bf', height = 4, width = 12)
            self.logbtn5.grid(columnspan=1)
            self.logbtn2 = Button(self, text="NOTEPAD", command=self._login_btn_clicked2, fg='#0000ff', height = 4, width = 12)
            self.logbtn2.grid(columnspan=1)
            self.logbtn3 = Button(self, text="""POWER POINT
""", command=self._login_btn_clicked3, fg='#8000ff', height = 4, width = 12)
            self.logbtn3.grid(columnspan=1)
            self.logbtn4 = Button(self, text="FACEBOOK", command=self._login_btn_clicked4, fg='#0059b3', height = 4, width = 12)
            self.logbtn4.grid(columnspan=2)

            self.logbtn0.grid(row=1, sticky=N)
            self.logbtn.grid(row=1, sticky=N)
            self.logbtn1.grid(row=2, sticky=N)
            self.logbtn2.grid(row=1, sticky=N)
            self.logbtn3.grid(row=2, sticky=N)
            self.logbtn4.grid(row=3, sticky=N)
            self.logbtn5.grid(row=3, sticky=N)
            self.logbtn6.grid(row=2, sticky=N)
            self.logbtn7.grid(row=3, sticky=N)

            self.logbtn0.grid(row=1, column=4)
            self.logbtn.grid(row=1, column=2)
            self.logbtn1.grid(row=2, column=2)
            self.logbtn2.grid(row=1, column=1)
            self.logbtn3.grid(row=2, column=1)
            self.logbtn4.grid(row=3, column=2)
            self.logbtn5.grid(row=3, column=1)
            self.logbtn6.grid(row=2, column=4)
            self.logbtn7.grid(row=3, column=4)


            self.pack()

        def _login_btn_clicked(self):
            dialog_title = "Responda por favor"
            dialog_text = "DESEJA ABRIR O EXCEL?"
            answer = messagebox.askquestion(dialog_title, dialog_text,)

            if answer == "yes":
                path = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Office/root/Office16/"
                os.chdir(path)
                os.system("EXCEL.exe")
            else:
                return

        def _login_btn_clicked1(self):
            dialog_title = "Responda por favor"
            dialog_text = "DESEJA ABRIR O WORD?"
            answer = messagebox.askquestion(dialog_title, dialog_text,)

            if answer == "yes":
                path = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Office/root/Office16/"
                os.chdir(path)
                os.system("WINWORD.exe")
            else:
                return

        def _login_btn_clicked2(self):
            dialog_title = "Responda por favor"
            dialog_text = "DESEJA ABRIR O NOTEPAD?"
            answer = messagebox.askquestion(dialog_title, dialog_text,)

            if answer == "yes":
                path = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++"
                os.chdir(path)
                os.system("notepad++.exe")
            else:
                return

        def _login_btn_clicked3(self):
            dialog_title = "Responda por favor"
            dialog_text = """DESEJA ABRIR O POWER
POINT?"""
            answer = messagebox.askquestion(dialog_title, dialog_text,)

            if answer == "yes":
                path = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Office/root/Office16"
                os.chdir(path)
                os.system("POWERPNT.exe")
            else:
                return

        def _login_btn_clicked4(self):
            dialog_title = "Responda por favor"
            dialog_text = "DESEJA IR PARA ESTE SITE?"
            answer = messagebox.askquestion(dialog_title, dialog_text,)

            if answer == "yes":
                webbrowser.open('https://www.facebook.com/francisco.neves.16718979')
            else:
                return

        def _login_btn_clicked0(self):
            dialog_title = "Responda por favor"
            dialog_text = "DESEJA IR PARA ESTE SITE?"
            answer = messagebox.askquestion(dialog_title, dialog_text,)

            if answer == "yes":
                webbrowser.open('https://www.skidrowreloaded.com/')
            else:
                return

        def _login_btn_clicked5(self):
            dialog_title = "Responda por favor"
            dialog_text = "DESEJA ABRIR O FILMORA?"
            answer = messagebox.askquestion(dialog_title, dialog_text,)

            if answer == "yes":
                path = "C:/Program Files/Wondershare/Filmora"
                os.chdir(path)
                os.system("Filmora.exe")
            else:
                return

        def _login_btn_clicked6(self):
            dialog_title = "Responda por favor"
            dialog_text = "DESEJA IR PARA ESTE SITE?"
            answer = messagebox.askquestion(dialog_title, dialog_text,)

            if answer == "yes":
                webbrowser.open('https://www.planetromeo.com/radar/home')
            else:
                return

        def _login_btn_clicked7(self):
            quit()           

    root = tk.Tk()
    lf = LoginFrame(root)
    root.mainloop()

def main():
    programs()

if __name__ == ("__main__"):
    main()
```

Comment: before anyone asks, there is the command self.pack() inserted in the code. the program runs fine, just want to hide or remove the cmd

Comment: The formatting of the code in your question is impossible to understand.

Comment: I think you need to use pythonw not python to run the program. python is a command line tool. pythonw is a GUI tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop using `os.system`; `os.system` runs the program in question in a shell, and on Windows, that means `cmd.exe`. Use the `subprocess` module to launch programs *without* shell wrapping and it should work just fine. For something like:

```
os.system("POWERPNT.exe")
```

just replace it [with `subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run):

```
subprocess.run(["POWERPNT.exe"])
```

Or to let it run in the background, [use `Popen` instead](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen). You *may* also want to look at [passing `startupinfo` on Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.STARTUPINFO) for specific behaviors, but try a plain run first.

Comment: subprocess.run works perfect, the cmd.exe won't popup. It crashes tkinter (after pressing the button, it opens the exe extension) for a while but it recovers.

Answer (score 0):

while converting .py to .exe  add this flag

```
 ---windowed
```

Comment: i have posted the full code, thanks for reply, can you provide more specific info now? many regards from francisco neves

Comment: you have created an .exe file which you are invoking from another .py file.this creates a command window. that is your problem right?

Comment: problem solved using #ShadowRanger sugestion "subprocess.run" command